# How to reverse a field in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to reverse a field in SQL Server 2008

Comment: `REVERSE('123')` gives `321` is that what you need? Otherwise please explain!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select reverse('abcdef')

------
fedcba

(1 row(s) affected)
```